# Secure boot ON/OFF while installing ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I wanna dual boot ubuntu 16 alongside windows 10. As a part of installation process its asking a checkbox to Turn Off Secure boot.
Should I click it or not. Please help.
Which is safe? I want to run both OS'es in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

you should check it. it let the kernel modules to load. ubuntu 16.04 come with the secure boot enabled because of EFI_SECURE_BOOT_SIG_ENFORCE in linux kernel 4.4.0-20 and later. you can later disable the secure boot when ever you want. Don't worry disabling the secure boot will not harm your windows. i have dual booted my system giving the key.
you may later face some problems after installing the ubuntu 16.04. you may refer [nvidi-361 login loop ubuntu 16.04 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761819/nvidi-361-login-loop-ubuntu-16-04-lts?noredirect=1#comment1139750_761819)

Comment: Now I want to load windows automatically after startup. Do i need to enable TURN OFF SECURE BOOT NOW?

Comment: You said it won't harm Windows. What I want to know is if disabling Secure Boot along the lines of this tutorial for Ubuntu will render the existing Ubuntu install unbootable: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS. This would be an after the fact change where the user has data they want to preserve on the Ubuntu OS but disable Secure Boot which was left enabled by default at install time.