# Ubuntu 16.04 GTX 850M cannot log in after switching to intel with nvidia 364.19 drivers installed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, 16.04

I had some problems installing the proprietary nvidia drivers. At the beginning they caused the log in screen fail to appear, then after running the command suggested here: [askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850) and checking that I had Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS I managed to have them work. Now the problem is that if I switch to the intel chipset and then log out I cannot log in again. And this happens if I switch using the nVidia X server application, "sudo prime-select intel" or the panel indicator (prime indicator). To be able to log back in I have to switch to a different tty, run "sudo prime-select nvidia" and go back to tty7. Furthermore if I run

```
sudo prime-switch intel
```

I get:

```
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
```

Du you have any suggestions on how to be able to switch to the power saving intel GPU?

Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761819/nvidi-361-login-loop-ubuntu-16-04-lts
try technique suggested in this question

Comment: Hi! Yes, it's the technique I used to have the nvidia drivers work and it's the same I linked. My problem was now not being able to switch to the intel chipset. But apparently removing the xorg.conf did the trick :/ thank you anyway.

Comment: Upvote the answer so max people solve their problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a very simple way. I deleted the xorg.conf...

First I tried moving to a textual tty, switch to intel and run "sudo nvidia-xconfig". After logging out and then logging in again I noticed that the resolution was messed up (only one, nearly 640x480) but at least it was not failing to log in. So I tried to remove xorg.conf and now it works!

Comment: there is no file "xorg.conf" on my machine. there is a directory /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d ... did you delete a file in that directory?